# R Yahoo Fantasy API - Permission

Tags: r, oauth, yahoo-api

I am having issues using the Yahoo Fantasy API. Using examples [here](http://ryankuhn.net/blog/Fantasy-Football-in-R-Part-I) and [here](https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-r-to-analyze-yahoo-fantasy-football-data/), I have developed a pretty hacky solution to get my connection set.

First, I create an oauth1 token with the following code:

```
library(httr)

cKey <- "mykey"
cSecret <- "mysecret"

oauth_endpoints("yahoo")
myapp <- oauth_app("yahoo", key = cKey, secret = cSecret)
token <- oauth1.0_token(oauth_endpoints("yahoo"), myapp)
```

Then I have another piece of code that gets me a signature:

```
yahoo    <-oauth_endpoints("yahoo")
myapp <- oauth_app("yahoo", key=cKey, secret=cSecret)
yahoo_token<- oauth2.0_token(yahoo, myapp, cache=T, use_oob = T)
sig <- sign_oauth1.0(myapp, yahoo_token$oauth_token, yahoo_token$oauth_token_secret)
```

It seems to me like I should only need one of these to access the API, but I can't make it work with just one.

Anyways, this does allow me to get my connection set up. In order to access the API, I need the game ID. Per instructions in one of the above-linked walkthroughs, I use this code to do that:

```
page_mlb <-GET("http://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/game/mlb?format=json", sig)
page_mlb_parse <- content(page_mlb, as="parsed", encoding="utf-8")
game_key <- page_mlb_parse[["fantasy_content"]][["game"]][[1]][["game_key"]]
```

That `game_key` ends up being `378`. Thus, I should be able to access something like the league standings for my league using the game key I just found along with my league ID of `94107` which is unique to my league.

```
leagueKey <- paste0(game_key,'.l.',lg_id)

baseURL     <- "http://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/league/"
standingsURL<-paste(baseURL, leagueKey, "/standings", sep="")
standings_page <- GET(standingsURL,sig)

standings_parse <- content(standings_page, as = "parsed", encoding = "utf-8")
```

But when I print that to the screen, I get:

```
> standings_parse
{xml_document}
<error lang="en-us" uri="http://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/league/378.l.94107/standings" xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng" xmlns="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng">
[1] <description>You are not allowed to view this page because you are not in this league.</description>
[2] <detail/>
```

The response: `You are not allowed to view this page because you are not in this league` is what has me hung up here. I am using the same Yahoo login to create the API that I used to set up my fantasy team.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you made any progress on this issue?

Comment: @Phil, nope, no progress to report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having similar struggles and I used Birchman's answer and a lot of trial and error.

Here's how I solved it.

Once you key and secret code from yahoo, you can do the following.  Of course, I've not shown mine.

```
options("httr_oob_default" = T)

cKey     <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
cSecret  <- "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

yahoo <- httr::oauth_endpoint(authorize ="https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth", access = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token", base_url = "https://fantasysports.yahooapis.com")

myapp <- httr::oauth_app("yahoo", key=cKey, secret = cSecret,redirect_uri = "oob")
```

Now, when you do the next section, you'll have a browser pop up.  You'll have to copy and paste the code provided.

```
httr::BROWSE(httr::oauth2.0_authorize_url(yahoo, myapp, scope="fspt-r", redirect_uri = myapp$redirect_uri))

passcode = "xxxxxxx"

yahoo_token <- httr::oauth2.0_access_token(yahoo,myapp,code=passcode)
```

The next section helps you build the url to get the data you need.

```
standings_page <- GET("https://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/game/nfl", add_headers(Authorization=paste0("Bearer ", yahoo_token$access_token)))
XMLstandings<- content(standings_page, as="parsed", encoding="utf-8")
doc<-xmlTreeParse(XMLstandings, useInternal=TRUE)
myList<- xmlToList(xmlRoot(doc))
game_key = myList$game$game_key
game_key
```

Now, the next chunk of code will extract the data you are looking for.

```
baseURL <- "https://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/league/"

leagueID <- "1244633"

tag <- "/scoreboard;week=1"

standingsURL <-paste0(baseURL,game_key,".l.",leagueID,tag)
standings_page <- GET(standingsURL, add_headers(Authorization = 
paste0("Bearer ", yahoo_token$access_token)))
XMLstandings <- content(standings_page, as = "parsed", encoding = "utf-8")

doc <- xmlTreeParse(XMLstandings, useInternal = TRUE)
myList <- xmlToList(xmlRoot(doc))
```

For more details, here is a [Fantasy Football Blog Post](https://dusty-turner.netlify.com/post/espn-yahoo-api-navigation/) I wrote.

Comment: This helped my authentication issue, thank you. I can consistently do that now. I noticed you are using some functions from the `XML` package. I believe that package is orphaned so I'll probably be converting this code to use `xml2` or just change the return options to pull back JSON. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're still having issues, but I struggled with this for a while until I found the solution.

Issue: **Yahoo has switched from OAuth1.0 to OAuth2.0.** That means many of the sample scripts you find online -- nearly all of which were created before this change -- are no longer functional.

In the sample code you've provided, it looks like *both* 1.0 and 2.0 are being used (one interesting note here: 1.0 functionality is used to create the "sig" variable -- a signed token -- which is no longer necessary in 2.0).

Here's a rewrite that should accomplish what you're trying to do without the pesky authorization issues:

```
library(httr)

cKey <- "mykey"
cSecret <- "mysecret"

b_url <- "https://fantasysports.yahooapis.com" #base url

#Create Endpoint
yahoo <- httr::oauth_endpoint(authorize = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/request_auth"
                              , access = "https://api.login.yahoo.com/oauth2/get_token"
                              , base_url = b_url)
#Create App
myapp <- httr::oauth_app("yahoo", key=cKey, secret = cSecret,redirect_uri = "oob")

#Open Browser to Authorization Code
httr::BROWSE(httr::oauth2.0_authorize_url(yahoo, myapp, scope="fspt-r"
                                          , redirect_uri = yahoo_app$redirect_uri))

#Create Token
yahoo_token <- httr::oauth2.0_access_token(yahoo,yahoo_app,code="[ENTER CODE FROM BROWSER HERE]")
save(yahoo_token,file="yahoo_token.Rdata")

leagueKey <- paste0(game_key,'.l.',lg_id)

baseURL     <- "https://fantasysports.yahooapis.com/fantasy/v2/league/"
standingsURL <- paste(baseURL, leagueKey, "/standings")
standings_page <- GET(standingsURL,
                      add_headers(Authorization=paste0("Bearer ", yahoo_token$access_token)))

standings_parse <- content(standings_page, as = "parsed", encoding = "utf-8")
```

Comment: Thank you, this is getting me much further. I think there might be a change needed on the `yahoo_app`. Should that just be `myapp`? When I make that change, things seem to go a little more smoothly. The `standings_parse` is returning a non-nonsensical result, but it is better than the access denied I was getting before. I probably just need to read more through the API docs.